# Hive Runtime Error while processing row in Hive [ClassCastException]

Tags: sql, hive

trying to run hive query, getting hive exception. pasted the query below. I think this problem due to dirty data(column of dim_id) or formatted of data, I am  new to Hive and I don't how to deal this!
I need your help!

this is fdm.fdm_szad_t_exp_dim_day schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `fdm.fdm_szad_t_exp_dim_day`(
  `mediatype` int COMMENT '**', 
  `dim_id` bigint COMMENT '**', 
  `dim_name` string COMMENT '***', 
  `adcrttype` string COMMENT '***')
COMMENT '***'
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dim_type` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://ns1018/user/jd_ad/ads_sz/fdm.db/fdm_szad_t_exp_dim_day'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'mart_name'='jd_ad', 
  'orc.compress'='SNAPPY', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1529396655')
```

this is bdm.bdm_szad_kafka_ad_media_click_hour schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `bdm.bdm_szad_kafka_ad_media_click_hour`( 
...
  `position_id` string COMMENT '***'
...)
COMMENT '***'
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `ftime` bigint)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://ns1018/user/jd_ad/ads_sz/bdm.db/bdm_szad_kafka_ad_media_click_hour'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'SENSITIVE_TABLE'='FALSE', 
  'last_modified_by'='ads_sz', 
  'last_modified_time'='1540360230', 
  'mart_name'='jd_ad', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1574760932')
```

this is query :

```
select
    t1.dim_id,
    t2.position_id
from
(select
    cast(dim_id as string) dim_id
from fdm.fdm_szad_t_exp_dim_day) t1
join
(select
    position_id
from bdm.bdm_szad_kafka_ad_media_click_hour
WHERE ftime >= 2020030100 and ftime < 2020030101 and agency_id != 2390456) t2
on t1.dim_id = t2.position_id
 ;
```

this is log of part:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:233)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:366)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:202)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:188)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:571)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:540)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1830)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
 ]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1830)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:233)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:366)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:202)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:188)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:571)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:540)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1830)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
 ]

      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:545)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
      ... 8 more

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString@c2e3264 of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString with arguments {泡泡射击_横幅:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 1
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1001)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:180)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:81)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:839)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:97)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:164)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:535)
      ... 9 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:977)
      ... 18 more
```

Comment: tag: I gess my problom due to drity data(column of dim_id) or formated of data

Comment: select
    min(dim_id)
from fdm.fdm_szad_t_exp_dim_day

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>    Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable)
>   on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString@c2e3264
>   of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString
>   with arguments
>   {泡泡射击_横幅:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 1

I suspect this has nothing to do with your query.
Validate your tables, like wise:

```
select 
   max(`mediatype`)
  ,max(`dim_id`)
  ,max(`dim_name`)
  ,max(`adcrttype`)
from `fdm.fdm_szad_t_exp_dim_day`
```

Comment: I has convert cast(dim_id as string) dim_id in my query